# Laravel hasOne does not trigger any sql request

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, has-one

I have a little issue with Laravel. I'm totally new with it, and am trying to create a multilang model for some content I have.

This is my configuration :

Database :

Table appartements : 
    1   id  int(10) 
    2   address varchar(255)
    3   postcode    int(11) 
    4   city    varchar(255)
    5   country varchar(255)
    6   created_at  timestamp
    7   updated_at      timestamp

Table appartement_langs
    1   id  int(10)
    2   language_id int(11) 
    3   appartement_id  int(11) 
    4   title   varchar(255)
    5   subtitle    varchar(255)
    6   description text
    7   created_at  timestamp
    8   updated_at  timestamp

Table languages
        1       id  int(10)
    2   locale  varchar(255)
    3   created_at  timestamp
    4   updated_at  timestamp

So basically I have the language_id and the appartement_id.

In my Appartement model I have the following :

```
    <?php

    class Appartement extends Eloquent {
        protected $guarded = array();

        public static $rules = array();

        public function gallery()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('Gallery');
        }

        public function languages()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('AppartementLang', 'language_id');
        }

        public function lang()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('AppartementLang');
        }
    }
```

When I try to get the field $appartement->lang()->title I get nothing.

Can you give me a hint ? Because I really don't know how to handle this :).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `lang()` you are actually returning the query partially built (so you can add on other conditions, etc..)

If you want to retrieve the language model you only have to use `lang`.

So:

```
$appartement->lang->title
```

If you `var_dump()` the `lang()` you will see for yourself.

In the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) you will see their relationship example calls:

```
$phone = User::find(1)->phone;
```